# What causes mongdb update to not insert value for particular field name?

Tags: mongodb

Noticed a case where mongodb does not insert a value for a particular field name(s).

Let's say that I've started with a collection of fields:

```sh
field1
field2
field3
field4
foobarFobarium1,
foobarFobarium2,
```

While developing, decided to drop the collection

```js
db.collection("xxx").drop()
```

Then after exec "updateOne", the "foobarFobarium1" and "foobarFobarium2" are empty while the other fields have values

```js
          db.collection("xxx").updateOne({
            wallet,
          }, {
            $set: {
              field1: "abc",
              field2: "abc",
              field3: "abc",
              field4: "abc",
              foobarFobarium1: "xxx",
              foobarFobarium2: "yyy",
            },
          },{
            upsert: true
          });
```

As a sanity check, exec "drop" and decided to pass the values of foobarFobarium1|2 to a different fieldname and the values are inserted although the foobarFobarium1|2 are displayed empty.

```js
          db.collection("xxx").updateOne({
            wallet,
          }, {
            $set: {
              field1: "abc",
              field2: "abc",
              field3: "abc",
              field4: "abc",
              foobar1: "xxx",
              foobar2: "yyy",
            },
          },{
            upsert: true
          });
```

It seems that the original field name persists and due to the type or something causes to not accept the value, but wonder if someone knows what's going on.

Comment: What do you have in the `wallet` variable?

Comment: @user14967413 that'll be an identifier which is a text type

Comment: There should be an object representing fitler, which in case of upsert may affect content of inserted document.